# How can I access the default value for ItemDisplayFunction?

Tags: dataset

Let's say I have some data I've imported and processed:

```
data = 
  {<|"timestamp" -> Now, "amount" -> Quantity[10, "USDollars"], "duration" -> Missing["reason 1"]|>,
   <|"timestamp" -> Today, "amount" -> Missing["reason 2"], "duration" -> Quantity[6, "Minutes"]|>}
```

Now I display that data with Dataset:

```
Dataset[data]
```

[image]

I'd prefer a different display for `timestamp`, so I define a function:

```
displayer[item_DateObject, ___] := DateString[item, "ISODateTime"];
displayer[item_, ___] := item; (* <-- I'd like to refer to the default display function here *)
```

And use it:

```
Dataset[data, ItemDisplayFunction -> (displayer[##] &)]
```

[image]

I like the default way of displaying the `Missing` and `Quantity` expressions, and would like to recover those by just applying the default display function--but I don't know how to discover that.

I know there are workarounds. I know I can reference rows and columns in my `displayer` function. I know I could handle `Missing`/`Quantity` explicitly. I know I could do more pre-processing. As you can imagine, my actual data is bigger than this, and my desired display function is more involved and isn't actually restricted to specific columns/rows (but instead to specific forms of data). So, it seems like the most elegant solution would be to only specify a display function for items that match my specified forms and then "fall-through" to the built-in, default display function. But I haven't been able to figure out what that function is. If it's not accessible, then I can apply the workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, `Dataset` is not a kernel function, so we can spelunk into its code.

```
displayer[item_DateObject, ___] := DateString[item, "ISODateTime"];
displayer[item_, ___] := TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`formatAtom[item];

Dataset[data, ItemDisplayFunction -> (displayer[#] &)]
```

[image]

As usually, beware of using such undocumented features as they may change in subsequent versions.

---

If you are curious, you can also see how this default formatter works by using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`formatAtom] ``. You will see something like:

```
TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`formatAtom[m_Missing] := 
  TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`missingIndicator[];

TypeSystem`NestedGrid`PackagePrivate`missingIndicator[] := Style["—", GrayLevel @ 0.75];
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! How did you know where to start spelunking?

Comment: @lericr, I started at `Dataset`. But then it takes a few steps down the rabbit hole to get to the formatting part ...

Comment: Sorry, treat me like I'm five. What do you mean "I started at Dataset"? Was it `GeneralUtilities``PrintDefinitions[Dataset]` and then you just searched exhaustively?

Comment: Exactly. First, I put an `Echo` to `ItemDisplayFunction` to see when it gets called. Then I keep putting new `Echo`s into various functions – with a "bisection" method (ie. before and after a function call) –  that get called when `Dataset` is created to determine where exactly `ItemDisplayFunction` is used. It's a poor man's solution, but it usually works :D

Comment: Ahh, I see. Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: Um, I guess I don't see. How do you "put an Echo to ItemDisplayFunction"? Like could I impose on you to provide concrete code that I can copy and execute? Everything I try blocks me from seeing the actual default value. Is there some basic knowledge area that I need to become aware of?

Comment: Oh, I see, you literally used `ItemDisplayFunction->Echo` which produced bad output but exposed a layer of functions. I was looking for some way to use `Echo` that just spit out the literal display function. Or am I still off base?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't write it precisely enough; you just put `Echo` next to your function, for example: `displayer[item_DateObject, ___] := (Echo["Hello!"]; DateString[item, "ISODateTime"])`. Or you may even wrap the whole thing with `Echo` because it returns the value: `displayer[item_DateObject, ___] := Echo@DateString[item, "ISODateTime"];`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more information. Thanks to Domen for the spelunking tips which led to these discoveries.

First, part of the documentation for `ItemDisplayFunction` is wrong. Specifically,

> With the option ItemDisplayFunction->f, the displayed item is given by f[item,position,dataset].

In fact, `f` needs to accept 4 arguments. Luckily for me, the fourth argument is the actual default display form!

So, in my toy example, I can write a display function like this:

```
displayer[item_DateObject, ___] := DateString[item, "ISODateTime"];
displayer[items___] := Last[{items}];
```

and use it like this:

```
Dataset[data, ItemDisplayFunction -> (displayer[##] &)]
```

[image]